# macOS numbers formula range problem

Tags: macos, numbers

I can't seem to find the equivalent of:

```
H2:2
```

In macOS Numbers app. This statement in a formula tells that the formula should take the cells from H2 to the end of the row into consideration.

I can't set it to a constant value, since the rows are constantly increasing, so I need a dynamic value.

EDIT:
This is what I was using in Google Sheets:

```
=COUNTIF(I3:3, 0)
```

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, the row (horizontally) or column (vertically)?  You mention increasing rows so that is what is confusing. If the rows increase That does not affect another row, increasing columns would. Would love to help if we can, please clarify perhaps with an example table. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

As of version version 4.1.1 (4338), unfortunately with **Numbers** one can define the entire row, but not from a specific column forward.

So, while `COUNTIF(I3:3, 0)` will resolve to an error, `COUNTIF(3:3, 0)` will work regardless of the row's length. (Increasing columns)

Example:

[image: COUNTIF(row, condition) example]

This would be a good feature suggestion for [Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback).

Answer (score 0):

Just give the column name. This: `SUM(H2;)` should give you the sum of all values in column H2. You do not need to provide a range.

Comment: I don't need values from the whole row. I need the function to count the data from a specific point of the row to its end. So doing the same for the row (SUM(h2)) won't work.